# How do I modify the aircraft weight and balance after a battery replacement?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, weight-and-balance

I am looking to replace my Gill battery with a Concord.  The regulations appear to allow me to do this as an owner.

However, the Concord battery weighs 2 lbs more.

I cant find it in the regs if I can legally modify the weight and balance for the airplane myself, or do I need an A&P to sign it off, possibly as a minor alteration?

Comment: You can recalculate the W&B and print up a new form but an A&P must sign off on the new W&B data.

Answer (score 2):

Is the Concord battery on the approved equipment list?  Is it approved to be in your airplane due to it being [PMA](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/pma/)'d?

The point is that the battery has to be approved by the FAA and if it isn't you'll need to get it approved.  It's not a major redesign requiring form 337 but a minor alteration to it's **approved** type certificate.

To answer your question, you can alter your weight and balance but it must be signed off by an A&P mechanic.